# preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Tags: php

```
$test =array('APP_TITLE' =>'ssfss');
update_define($test);

function update_define($arr_con){
    $file='config.php';
    $fileContent= file_get_contents($file);
    $i = 0;
    $define_arr = array();
    $new_value_arr = array();

    foreach ($arr_con as $constant => $vale){
        $line = getLine($constant);

        $define_arr[$i] = $line;
        if(($vale == 'true') || ($vale == 'false')){
            $new_value_arr[$i] = "define('$constant', $vale)";
        }else{
            $new_value_arr[$i] = "define('$constant', '$vale')";
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $modified=preg_replace($define_arr, $new_value_arr, $fileContent);

    file_put_contents($file, $modified);

}

function getLine($string){
    $ret = '';
    $file = fopen("config.php", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
    //Output a line of the file until the end is reached
    $i = 0;
    while(!feof($file))
    {
        $i++;
        $line = fgets($file);
        $pos = strpos($line, $string);
        if( $pos !== false ){
            $test =array('APP_TITLE' =>'ssfss');
            update_define($test);

function update_define($arr_con){
    $file='config.php';
    $fileContent= file_get_contents($file);
    $i = 0;
    $define_arr = array();
    $new_value_arr = array();

            foreach ($arr_con as $constant => $vale){
                $line = getLine($constant);

                $define_arr[$i] = $line;
                if(($vale == 'true') || ($vale == 'false')){
                    $new_value_arr[$i] = "define('$constant', $vale)";
                }else{
                    $new_value_arr[$i] = "define('$constant', '$vale')";
                }
                $i++;
                }
                $modified=preg_replace($define_arr, $new_value_arr, $fileContent);

                file_put_contents($file, $modified);

            }

        function getLine($string)
        {

        $ret = '';
            $file = fopen("config.php", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
            //Output a line of the file until the end is reached
            $i = 0;
            while(!feof($file))
            {
                $i++;
                $line = fgets($file);
                $pos = strpos($line, $string);
                if( $pos !== false ){
                    //          echo $i.'<br/>';
                    $line = str_replace("define(", "define\(",$line);
                    $line = str_replace(");","\);", $line);
                    $ret= $line;
                }
            }
            fclose($file);
            return $ret;
        }
                $line = str_replace("define(", "define\(",$line);
                    $line = str_replace(");","\);", $line);
                    $ret= $line;
                }
            }
            fclose($file);
            return $ret;
        }
```

config.php file

```
<?PHP
    define ( 'APP_TITLE', 'test com title' ); 
    define('COMPANY_ADDRESS_2', '49 sd d');
    define('COMPANY_ZIPCODE', '2085');
    define('COMPANY_PHONE', '+44 (0)2 8007-5554');
    define('COMPANY_FAX', '+62 (0)2 253-9479');
?>
```

above code gave to me below error

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Edit_file/abc.php on line 46
Array ( [0] => define\('APP_TITLE', 'test com title' \); ) /nArray ( [0] => define('APP_TITLE', 'ssfss') )
```

i' were tring to edit some php file using my above method but calling preg_replace() method give me some errors. please help to solve this problem

Comment: `$define_arr = Array ( [0] => define\('APP_TITLE', 'some test' \) );`
why are you backslashing the brackets?

Comment: instead of `preg_replace`, which uses regular expressions, look into `str_replace`. Also: Constants? really? defined in an array? `define` returns a bool, too, so you're quite likely attempting to `preg_replace` `array(true)` with `array(true)`... really: RTFM

Comment: This question makes little sense. Please show actual valid code. It's hard to tell what's what here.

Answer (score 3):

When using `preg_replace` the pattern should be delimited, so the parser knows where the pattern starts and ends. Often used delimiter is the forward slash `/`:

```
$a = preg_replace(array("/1/", "/3/"), array("10", "30"), "this is a 1 2 3 test");
```

`$a` now holds `this is a 10 2 30 test`.

What you need to do is enclose your pattern with delimiters:

```
$define_arr = Array ( [0] => "/define('APP_TITLE', 'some test' )/" );
$new_value_arr = Array ( [0] => "define('APP_TITLE', 'ssfss')" ):


preg_replace($define_arr, $new_value_arr, $fileContent);
```

That should work.

Note though, you don't really need an array or `preg_replace` for this simple replacements. use `str_replace` instead.

Comment: $define_arr = Array ( [0] => "/define('APP_TITLE', 'some test' )/" );
not work for me but i change preg_replace to str_replace that's work for me thanks