# preg_replace not working as i want it to

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I'm trying to manipulate text by using the `preg_replace()` function, the code is self explanatory:

```
$fff = "12345678910";
echo $fff . "<br>";

$last = substr($fff,-5);
echo $last . "<br><br>";

$replace = "...";

$final = preg_replace($last,$replace,$fff);
echo $final;
```

So if you don't understand I want to shorten `$fff` by 5 characters and replace it with `...` then store the full word into `$final` where I can use it later. But I get this error:

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\htdocs\test.php on line 11
```

Line 11:

```
$final = preg_replace($last,$replace,$fff);
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Please take a quick look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13025429/3387762
It should answer Your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why to use preg_replace it could be done as

```
echo str_replace($last,$replace,$fff);
```

Comment: Thanks alot, although can you tell me the difference?

Comment: you can check here which has better description http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245513/php-preg-replace-preg-match-vs-php-str-replace

Answer (score 1):

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) uses [regular expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php). You are probably looking for [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
str_replace($last, $replace, $fff);
```